# How to read a dot file using a Boost Library

Tags: boost, graphviz, boost-graph

i am currently using boost graph lib to compute strongly connected component, but the example on their page seems to be too old to work, so how can I read a file into a GraphvizDigraph Object using Boost 1.48 now ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the full `GraphvizDigraph` information?  If you only need some of the vertex and edge properties, you can use `read_graphviz` function to load the graph into an `adjacency_list` structure.